# Showing text outside the figure limits

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to add text on top of a panel of subplots as labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 4, figsize=(6.83, 9.19))
# Plot something
for axes in axs.ravel():
    axes.plot(range(5))
# Add some labels
fig.text(0.25, 1.01, "Label #1", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold', ha='center')
fig.text(0.75, 1.01, "Label #2", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold', ha='center')
fig.text(0.125, 0.99, "Sublabel #1", fontsize=10, ha='center')
fig.text(0.375, 0.99, "Sublabel #2", fontsize=10, ha='center')
fig.text(0.625, 0.99, "Sublabel #3", fontsize=10, ha='center')
fig.text(0.875, 0.99, "Sublabel #4", fontsize=10, ha='center')
# Save figure
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('./temp.png', dpi=300)
```

However, because the labels are above the figure, they cannot be seen in the saved figure (though they can be seen on the ipython qtconsole). Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
fig.savefig('./temp.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

to adjust the figure when saving. You can also set the figure size properly since the beginning, adding before the "Create figure":

```
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The `bbox_inches='tight'` worked great. As for set figure size property - I already did that in `plt.subplots(fig=(width, height))`, but it did not help. Because however large the figure was set, the subplots will always fill it up.

Comment: There is still one problem though - by using `bbox_inches='tight'`, the figure size in uncontrolled. Is there a way to specify the bbox size?

Comment: @ShawnWang does it get completely uncontrolled or it just extends in order to fit the text outside the limits

Comment: @ShawnWang perhaps if you set `figsize` in the `savefig()` instead of in `figure()` it will respect the specified size...

Comment: Hi Saullo, thank you for the help! It is not entirely uncontrolled, because it is just cutting the white margins to fit the text, which is great on the vertical direction. On the horizontal direction, I'd like to remain the same width... But this is minor. Thanks for getting it to work! :)

Comment: I don't think the `savefig` can take `figsize` as a keyword though... Tried it and it got ignored.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks again to Saullo's answer, I think that answers my original question. However, I ended up using a different solution because I think this has better control of the page size:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 4, figsize=(6.83, 9.19))
# Plot something
for axes in axs.ravel():
    axes.plot(range(5))
# Add some labels
fig.text(0.25, 1., "Label #1", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold', ha='center', va='top')
fig.text(0.75, 1., "Label #2", fontsize=10, fontweight='bold', ha='center', va='top')
fig.text(0.125, 0.98, "Sublabel #1", fontsize=10, ha='center', va='top')
fig.text(0.375, 0.98, "Sublabel #2", fontsize=10, ha='center', va='top')
fig.text(0.625, 0.98, "Sublabel #3", fontsize=10, ha='center', va='top')
fig.text(0.875, 0.98, "Sublabel #4", fontsize=10, ha='center', va='top')
# Save figure
fig.tight_layout()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=.95)
fig.savefig('./temp.png', dpi=300)
```

Basically, the trick is:

1) Add the `va='top'` to text, and let the y-coord of the text to be < 1 so they are within bounds;

2) Use `fig.subplots_adjust(top=.95)` to save space for the text. Note: this must be after `fig.tight_layout()`!